# how to expose a raw ruby file (with interpolation) on my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I would like to be able to generate a public rails template file on my rails project (which is about making rails projects!). This file should look like this to the user:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/rails-templates/master/devise.rb

However we need to interpolate the file first. In my mind having a template.html.erb view and then some how exposing it as a raw ruby file would be ideal. This would mean the final url would look something like:

www.thing.com/projects/1/tempalte.rb, and the contents of this file would be different to the ones at www.thing.com/projects/2/template.rb.

I don't know how to solve this problem, but am researching a lot. If you have any ideas it would be great to know them. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by interpolate the file first? Changing some strings to a input from the user?

Comment: You need to give us some code and error. Like that, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Sorry, I am not close enough to really be writing useful code yet. I don't know how to get into the problem to start writing. We have tried a lot of things, like having a route to a static page (get 'template.rb', to: 'pages#template'), and then having a template method in the pages controller and a template.html.erb file in the pages views, however this was not useful.

Comment: Start by: A. Learn how low level ERB templating works. B. Read [Rails Application Templates](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) and [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html). C. Look at existing work like the [rails-templates](https://github.com/lewagon/rails-templates) gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track: the `.erb` suffix tells the eRuby templating system to run text between `<%`, `<%#`, or `<%=` and `%>` as Ruby code.

Then, the `.erb` suffix is stripped from the file name, and what's left is the file that Rails will use for the response. If your view is named `template.html.erb`, then after the internal Ruby code is evaluated, you will have a `template.html` file.

If you instead want a `template.rb` file for your response, your view should be `template.rb.erb`. Only code between the above delimiters will be evaluated and replaced.

So, if you have a `get_custom_text` method that returns the string `adding some custom text`, and you have the following in a `template.rb.erb` view file:

```
puts 'Hello, world!'
puts 'Now <%= get_custom_text %>...'
puts 'Goodbye, world!'
```

then after evaluation, you'll have a `template.rb` file that contains:

```
puts 'Hello, world!'
puts 'Now adding some custom text...'
puts 'Goodbye, world!'
```